# How to use a built-in tcl power function?

Tags: math, tcl

I am using this tcl version
/tools/tcl/8.4.11/linux64/bin/tcl

May i know how can i use the built in power function in my tcl script?

I tried this but it does not work.

```
namespace import ::tcl::mathfunc::*
puts [pow 10 2]
```

```
unknown namespace in import pattern "::tcl::mathfunc::*"
    while executing
"namespace import ::tcl::mathfunc::\*"
```

May i know why?

Answer (score 1):

The `::tcl::mathfunc` namespace was added in Tcl 8.5 and is not supported in Tcl 8.4. In Tcl 8.5+ you can use

```
namespace import ::tcl::mathfunc::*
pow 10 2
# -> 100.0
```

as well as calling `pow` from within `expr`, but in Tcl 8.4 and earlier you must use

```
expr {pow(10, 2)}
# -> 100.0
```

The `mathfunc` commands, when present, can be invoked as regular Tcl commands *or* be called as pseudofunctions in the expression script passed to `expr`. In the latter case, C-style syntax with parantheses and commas is used. The point of having them is mainly that it makes it easier to extend `expr` with new math functions. As a sideeffect, invoking `expr` can be avoided altogether for the simplest calculations.

The `pow` function returns a floating-point value, just as in C. As Donal Fellows describes in his answer (q.v.), integer exponentiation can be specified by using the `**` operator (which is also a separate command: `tcl::mathop::**`). This operator is Tcl 8.5+ only.

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [mathfunc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm), [mathop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm)

Comment: @Pi-Turn Yes. Expected and defined to work that way. Before bignums — an 8.5 feature — the useful range of exponentiation on integers was so small that we simply didn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

That feature was introduced in Tcl 8.5. In 8.4 and before, functions were implemented using a special API that nobody really understood (passing around pointers to `Tcl_Value` structures, which were rather strange).

The `pow()` function is a floating point function in all versions of Tcl (even if written as a call to `::tcl::mathfunc::pow`). Integer exponentiation is only available via the `**` operator (***requires Tcl 8.5***, which was also the first version to support arbitrary size integers):

```
puts [expr { 10 ** 2 }]
```

```
# Note the namespace
puts [tcl::mathop::** 10 2]
```

```
namespace import tcl::mathop::*
puts [** 10 2]
```

The `**` operator is exactly equivalent to `pow()` if either of its arguments is a floating point number (and will indeed call the same function in the standard C math library behind the scenes).

Comment: To clarify for the inexperienced, these are two separate namespaces: `pow` lives in `::tcl::mathfunc` (for math functions) while `**` lives in `::tcl::mathop` (for math operators).